# Python, map function applied to list of objects' attributes

Tags: python, list, object, lambda, vectorization

For no practical reason whatsoever, I'm interested in applying the map function to a list of objects, and more specifically, triggering a method therein.

Consider this example class:

```py
class Something:

  def __init__(self):
    self.attr = 0

  def step(self):
    self.attr += 1
```

Now, using for loops, I can iteratively execute the step method for each object in a list and view the results.

```py
obj_list1 = [Something() for i in range(10)]
for elem in obj_list1:
  elem.step()

[elem.attr for elem in obj_list1]  
>>>
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

However, if I try to map using a lambda function, things go awry:

```py
obj_list2 = [Something() for i in range(10)]
list(map(lambda x: x.step(), obj_list2))
>>> 
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
```

Note in this last code snippet, I was expecting a list of Something objects, not the attr attributes. However, None was returned in each instance.

My questions are: (A) Why is None returned for each element? And (B) How should one act upon a list of objects in a vectorized manner?

Edit: As an answer noted, I've got no return value in the step method. Likely several ways to fix this, one such approach which doesn't alter this class, itself, is below:

```py
def trigger(obj):
  obj.step()
  return obj.attr

obj_list3 = [Something() for i in range(10)]
list(map(trigger, obj_list3))  
>>>
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Nonetheless, is map a completely weird way to work with objects in a vectorized manner? Is there a preferred alternative? Etc.

Edit2: In my original question, referencing `obj_list2`, while a list of `None` values was returned, when I investigated the attributes in the list, all of them were increased to 1. Interesting finding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With map `step` is being called but your step function has no return statement so the default return of `None` is used.

If you want the map to end up with a list of the Something objects like you said you could `return self` from step:

```py
def step(self):
    self.attr += 1
    return self # or perhaps return self.attr
```

Though map is not necessarily the right thing to use here since the idea with map is it transforms things of one value into another, whereas your `step` is changing the objects internally in place.

I think the for loop way was fine:

```py
for elem in obj_list1:
  elem.step()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function step has no return value

```
def step(self):
     self.attr += 1
```

So mapping this onto anything returns a list filled with `None`

In your other example you returned `elem.attr`, that's why you got a different result.

For the second question, after

```
obj_list3 = [Something() for i in range(10)]
list(map(trigger, obj_list3))
```

print out the `obj_list3` to see if each object has been changed by the mapping attempt.